# Wordpress renames files when no duplicate is found

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have code that relies upon a certain file naming convention. When I stopped working locally and made a new database and setup online and went to upload the images for the posts. Wordpress adds a -1 or -2 to my images even though it is a fresh db and fresh wordpress install.

The naming conventions I have are like so..

cover_somename.jpg
cover_somename_bg.jpg

Why would it make my files like cover_somename_bg-1.jpg when there are NO DUPLICATES in the media library. How can I turn this renaming feature off/ rename the files myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you upload image on local it will create move image to upload folder. And while you moving project to live you create new data base you have only remove the image name from the data base table. 
>   But you image still remain on Upload folder under the month folder that you have added
>   When you upload the same file name on live server on same month then it will check for "if file already exist or not if already exist then it will rename new uploaded file as you get.

you create new data base so you old image wouldn't display on admin so you need to clear the folder under the upload folder then it work fine please try once.

Answer (score 0):

Ah images aren't in the DB turns out they are in uploads folder and if the uploads folder has images but its a fresh install the media library will be empty but will act like it has those files and renaming will occur.